# Winsock lag, test connection speed

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

I'm making a two player turn based game using Winsock, C++, and Win32. The problem is, I need a means of determining the current connection speed (or lag time) of each player.

If a players' connection speed is too slow, I do not want his (or her) opponent to have to wait an extra 20 seconds each per move (due to lag).

To prevent this unecessary waiting, players with too high of lag (or too slow of a ***current*** connection speed) will not be permitted to play in certain areas of the game.

Does anyone know a means of determining a clients' connection speed, or current lag?

I do not even know where to start with this, so any help will be appreciated.

I read up on some stuff concerning pinging, and I was curious to know if there was a method (or some winsock function) that could enable me to ping a clients computer from the server, or ping the server from the client?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can discover the "ping" time for a connection quite easily...

One program sends a special message containing a timestamp, which the other replies to, using the timestamp of the original message. Then when the first program receives the reply it can compare the timestamp in the sent message to the current time, thereby getting a "ping" time.

Comment: This is an awesome idea, and I don't think there is another means of doing it really, however I want to wait around a little while longer to see if anyone else has any input on the topic, if not I'll accept your answer, thanks.